# Extension for Live Magento Inventory?

Tags: inventory, magento

I need a extension I can buy, so I can get change my stock levels via a CSV (comma-separated values) from my supplier.
The SKU (stock keeping unit) matches on my store and my supplier, so I just need something I can plug between the two so I can get real time stock level changes.
I don't want to do this manually and without going through the magento product CSV and changing 1000 products every time I get CSV from supplier.

Comment: Please [edit] your question so that is better to read (capitalization, white space, interpunction, explain abbreviations). It is in your interest that we don't have to puzzle and squint.

Comment: Have you looked at magmi?

Comment: Tools like Magmi (directly writing sql) will suffer in the long run, because import not imports a bit differently (repository->save() instead of direct sql as it was before) and because of the newly introduced interceptors it will be hard to build a sql-data-pump that will not break with 3rd party data-handling.